# 'They are' or 'These are'

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, personal-pronouns, demonstratives

Which sentence sounds more natural?

1. **These** are first and foremost ethical, not medical questions.
2. **They** are first and foremost ethical, not medical questions.

Comment: Deepnds entirely on context, and is probably off-topic as 'writing advice'. All that can be said at present is that they are both grammatical.

Comment: The sentence stood alone, without any context.

Comment: That seems improbable, since both *These* and *They* must refer to preceding nouns. If there really is no context, neither sentence makes any sense, so neither can sound natural.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference I see between the sentences is *proximity*, although they are not physical objects. When I use *these*, it's like the one I'm talking about is near to me, as opposed to using *they*.

It's also like saying,

> These beliefs are the truth.
>
> They are the truth.

When you use *these*, you can specify the subject, which in this case, *beliefs*. The second sentence that uses *they* totally substitutes *beliefs*.

Both are grammatically correct. *These* and *they* are both pronouns.

You are asking if which sentence sounds more natural. It depends upon on the speaker. I would use different gestures with *these* and *they*.